# Motion Not Working- site can't be reach

Tags: camera, motion

I installed motion to do live streaming with my webcam.
Before this, I have tested the webcam with taking photo, it's working.
I have configured the motion.conf and set stream_localhost to off.

When I access the ipaddress:8081, google chrome show site can't be reached. `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Please note that i have a wordpress site on the ipaddress port 80 (default).
Is that the cause that i can't play live stream?

Please assist, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that motion service is running.
If you run it as service (daemon) you can check it with following command:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

If you see a minus [-] sign in front of motion you must first start it with

```
sudo service motion start
```

Then you may see the streaming video.

Comment: Hi, i have check the running service, but motion is not in the list. I have config the file `etc/default/motion` to set daemon to `yes` and start the service. Any idea?

Comment: If motion is not in the list, then it is not running. Can you post your config file? My motion.conf file is in `/etc/motion/motion.conf`. Is there anything in log file `/var/log/motion.log` or system default logfile?

Answer (score 2):

probably just this parameter to set off in motion.conf file to allow external connections :

```
# Restrict stream connections to localhost only (default: on)
stream_localhost off
```